# BackGroundWorker only allowing two threads at one time

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Okay folks,  Gonna drop a lot of code here for this problem since I am new to multithreading and I don't want to leave anything out.

**The problem:**  I have a UserControl from which I am downloading data feed files from vendors. I want to be able to process these several at a time, however, the way I have set up the BackGroundWorker, it is only running two downloads at a time, while the others seem to "wait in line" for **one** of the other two to complete before starting.  The ones that are waiting, make it to the first "GetResponse" call in the FTPDownload().

If I cancel any one of the currently running downloads, the ones "in waiting" never start.

I am using States in the DoWork event to let it decide which process to start, and the same states are read in the WorkComplete event to decide how to end the process.

Everything works fine, other than what I described.

**The code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GooeyPC_CCSE;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Gooey_Manager
{
    public partial class DFProgressControl : UserControl
    {
        BackgroundWorker _bg_worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        #region Private Members and Public Accessors
        /// <summary>
        /// Get/Set DFProgressControl Vendor Name
        /// </summary>
        public string VendorName
        {
            get { return lblDFP_VendorName.Text; }
            set { lblDFP_VendorName.Text = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get/Set DFProgressControl CurrentState
        /// </summary>
        public string CurrentState
        {
            get { return lblDFP_CurrentState.Text; }
            set { lblDFP_CurrentState.Text = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get/Set DFProgressControl RecordOfNum
        /// </summary>
        public string RecordOfNum
        {
            get { return lblDFP_RecordOfNum.Text; }
            set { lblDFP_RecordOfNum.Text = value; }
        }

        private AffiliateServiceProviderItem _aff_svc_prov = new AffiliateServiceProviderItem();
        public AffiliateServiceProviderItem AffiliateSvcProvider
        {
            get { return _aff_svc_prov; }
            set { _aff_svc_prov = value; }
        }

        private VendorSiteInfoItem _vsi = new VendorSiteInfoItem();
        public VendorSiteInfoItem VendorSiteInfo
        {
            get { return _vsi; }
            set { _vsi = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// DataFeeder States
        /// </summary>
        public enum ObjectState
        {
            Nothing = 0,
            Canceling = 1,
            Download = 2,
            Unzip = 3,
            Prestage = 4,
            Validate = 5,
            Move_to_DB = 6,
            Destroy = 7
        }
        private ObjectState _feeder_state = ObjectState.Nothing;
        public ObjectState FeederState
        {
            get { return _feeder_state; }
            set { _feeder_state = value; }
        } 
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vendor_id"></param>
        public DFProgressControl(int vendor_id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Initialize member data
            this._vsi = GooeyDataFactory.GetVendorSiteInfo(vendor_id);
            this._aff_svc_prov = GooeyDataFactory.GetAffiliatSvcProviderByID(_vsi.AffiliateSvcProviderID);
            VendorName = _vsi.SiteName;
            CurrentState = FeederState.ToString();
            RecordOfNum = "";

            //Background worker settings
            _bg_worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

            //Background worker event handlers
            _bg_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(workerDataFeeder_DoWork);
            _bg_worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workerDataFeeder_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        private void workerDataFeeder_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (FeederState)
            {
                case ObjectState.Download:
                    this.ProductDataFeedDownload(VendorName);
                    break;
                case ObjectState.Unzip:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void workerDataFeeder_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (FeederState)
            {
                case ObjectState.Download:
                    lblDFP_RecordOfNum.Text = "Download Complete";
                    FeederState = ObjectState.Nothing;
                    break;
                case ObjectState.Unzip:
                    FeederState = ObjectState.Nothing;
                    break;
                case ObjectState.Canceling:
                    lblDFP_RecordOfNum.Text = "Operation Canceled";
                    pbDFP_ProgressBar.Value = 0;
                    FeederState = ObjectState.Nothing;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            CurrentState = FeederState.ToString();
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Data Feeder Process menu items
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /// <summary>
        /// Download vendor's data feed file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void downloadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_bg_worker.IsBusy)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(VendorName + " Data Feeder is busy with " + CurrentState + "\nCancel Operation to do something else.");
            }
            else
            {
                FeederState = ObjectState.Download;
                CurrentState = FeederState.ToString();
                lblDFP_RecordOfNum.Text = "Preparing to download...";
                pbDFP_ProgressBar.Value = 0;
                _bg_worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cancel current operation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void cancelOperationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_bg_worker.IsBusy)
            {
                FeederState = ObjectState.Canceling;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No operation to stop for " + VendorName + " data feeder.");
            }
        }

        private void destroyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Data Feed Stuff
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /// <summary>
        /// Download Vendor's data feed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vendor_name"></param>
        /// <param name="pb"></param>
        /// <param name="status_text"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public byte[] ProductDataFeedDownload(string vendor_name)
        {
            string filename = Regex.Match(this._vsi.DFFTPProd, @"(\w|[-.])+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).ToString();
            byte[] data_feed = FTPDownload(this._vsi.DFFTPProd, this._aff_svc_prov.FTPUser, this._aff_svc_prov.FTPPassword);

            if (data_feed.Length != 0)
            {
                //Write the bytes to a file
                //NOTE: Do I really need to be Using Windows.Forms for this. System.IO should have the necessary methods?
                SaveFileDialog save_data_feed = new SaveFileDialog();
                save_data_feed.FileName = this._vsi.DFFileTextProd + "\\" + filename;
                FileStream newFile = new FileStream(save_data_feed.FileName, FileMode.Create);
                newFile.Write(data_feed, 0, data_feed.Length);
                newFile.Close();
            }
            return data_feed;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Connects to the FTP server and downloads the file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="FTPAddress"></param>
        /// <param name="username"></param>
        /// <param name="password"></param>
        /// <param name="pb"></param>
        /// <param name="status_text"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private byte[] FTPDownload(string FTPAddress, string username, string password)
        {
            byte[] downloadedData = new byte[0];

            try
            {
                //Create FTP request
                //Note: format is ftp://server.com/file.ext
                FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress) as FtpWebRequest;

                //Get the file size first (for progress bar)
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true; //don't close the connection
                int dataLength = 999999;
                dataLength = (int)request.GetResponse().ContentLength;//This does not work for Tigerdirect download. Causes error.                

                //Now get the actual data
                request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress) as FtpWebRequest;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = false; //close the connection when done

                //Streams
                FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
                Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream();

                //Download to memory
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //downloads in chuncks
                decimal bytesDownloaded = 0;
                bool cancel = false;
                while (!cancel)
                {
                    //Try to read the data
                    int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Write the downloaded data
                        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesDownloaded += bytesRead;

                        //Show Progress
                        ShowProgress(bytesRead, dataLength);

                        //Check for cancelation request
                        if (this.FeederState == ObjectState.Canceling)
                        {
                            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Click OK to stop current operation for " + VendorName + " data feeder.", "Cancel?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                            {
                                _bg_worker.CancelAsync();
                                cancel = true;
                                memStream = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.FeederState = ObjectState.Download;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Convert the downloaded stream to a byte array
                if (memStream != null)
                {
                    downloadedData = memStream.ToArray();
                    memStream.Close();
                }

                //Clean up
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

            username = string.Empty;
            password = string.Empty;
            return downloadedData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update progress bar and Record of Num values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="progress"></param>
        /// <param name="upper_bound"></param>
        private void ShowProgress(int progress, int upper_bound)
        {
            //Current State
            lblDFP_CurrentState.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lblDFP_CurrentState.Text = this.FeederState.ToString();
            });

            //Current Progress
            pbDFP_ProgressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                pbDFP_ProgressBar.Maximum = upper_bound;
                if (pbDFP_ProgressBar.Value + progress < upper_bound)
                {
                    pbDFP_ProgressBar.Value += progress;
                }
                else
                {
                    pbDFP_ProgressBar.Value = upper_bound;
                }
            });

            //Current value of progress over upper bound
            lblDFP_RecordOfNum.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lblDFP_RecordOfNum.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(pbDFP_ProgressBar.Value)/1024/1024).ToString("0.00") + " of " + (Convert.ToDecimal(upper_bound)/1024/1024).ToString("0.00") + " MB read.";
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm certain I am missing something fundamental here, and I hope someone can enlighten me.  Like I said, very new to the threading stuff - though I am pleased I got it this far; it's not working as I intend.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I should also add how I instantiate the UserControl

```
  //Data Feed Tab
private void btnStartDataFeed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DFProgressControl _df_prog_ctl = new DFProgressControl((int)lbDataFeedVendorList.SelectedValue); 
    if (_df_control_list.Find(o => o.VendorSiteInfo.VendorSiteInfoID == (int)lbDataFeedVendorList.SelectedValue) == null)
    {
        //Add instance of object to Data Feeder list
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(_df_prog_ctl);
        _df_control_list.Add(_df_prog_ctl);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is already an active data feeder for " + GooeyDataFactory.GetVendorSiteInfo(_df_prog_ctl.VendorSiteInfo.VendorSiteInfoID).SiteName + " doing " + _df_prog_ctl.FeederState + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: It just dawned on me that maybe the affiliate source only allows two active downloads from the same IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background worker is working correctly.  The problem is the source only allows two active downloads to run concurrently from the same IP.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: ,that's not an answer ! you can comment it :)

Comment: @zey in what respect is it not an answer?